# Handler.postDelayed() causing huge heap size of android.os.message

Tags: java, android, memory, memory-leaks, handler

Hi i have multiple handlers in my  app and after playing for around 5 minutes the retained heap size of android.os.message is 10mb. How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use one handler instead of many and post everything to it
2. Use `Message.obtain()` to create messages, and not the constructor
3. Avoid postDelayed

Comment: thank for your response. what can i use instead of postdelayed cause i use that a lot